# Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder

Tags: java, ssl, applet, keystore

I have imported the CA, Intermediate CA to the java trusted store(cacerts) and looks like all the things are working except the below exception sows in the Java Console.

```
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
network: Connecting http://localhost:389/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: Revocation Status Unknown
com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.doRevocationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.doRevocationCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationCheckHelper.checkRevocationStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509TrustManagerDelegate.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManagerDelegate.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.X509Extended7DeployTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.cache.JarCacheUtil.preload(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager._loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException
        at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(Unknown Source)
        ... 35 more
```

I am not sure why it is looking for http://localhost:389 and what is wrong in this ?

Is my CA certificate has any error to communicate the CRL certificate ?

I copy and pasted the crl site which is mentioned in my certificate and that site is not reachable as well.

Kindly do help and Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I suspect that my certificate is pointing to CRL Distribution Point with URL ldap///, but when we invoke the jnlp the java may be replacing ldap by localhost:389. Are you using a certificate that points to LDAP server for revocation cert ?

Comment: Hi @jux, I saw that in my CA certificate is pointed to ldap:/// without hostname so its got failed to connect ladp so java is taking default hostname as localhost and port as 389.

`Have you found any solution for this ?


1. Check with CA Certificate authorities
2. Select **Do not check (not recommended)** option in Java Control Panel > Advance Tab > Perform TLS certificate revocation checks on. **NOT RECOMMENDED** `